# How to use multiple wikipedia categories for Quick Intersection?

Tags: wikipedia

I'm using http://tools.wmflabs.org/quick-intersection/index.php to get a list of articles within categories but I have a list of over 35 categories and I'd like to use Quick Intersection to get the articles. Problem I have found, and perhaps I just don't know what I'm doing, but I can't seem to add multiple categories within the tool.

Every time I try and add multiple categories separated by a new line I get some strange articles. Any advice? Thanks

Comment: What categories were you trying to use? Could you include a link to the query you tried?

Comment: @NinjaBearMonkey `A-League_players`, `Allsvenskan_players` etc... I found out that the tool above does intersection so only articles that appear in both are shown. Do you know of a tool that does union instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for union, CatScan 2 (http://tools.wmflabs.org/catscan2/catscan2.php) can do that. It also has quite a few more features, at the expense of being slower. For the examples you gave, you would something like http://tools.wmflabs.org/catscan2/catscan2.php?categories=A-League_players%0D%0AAllsvenskan_players&comb%5Bunion%5D=1.

Comment: Oh wow perfect. I did try using CatScan 2 union a few days ago but for whatever reason it didn't work for me. Thanks!

Comment: Note that you can do union on QuickIntersection if you're wanting the union of *all* subcategories of a given category - put the parent category in "root categories" and set "depth" to an appropriate level. You'll need to be careful how deep you let it go, though - the category tree is very messy.